# Handlebars is not defined error in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, javascript

How can we load handlebars Js library in Magento 2. I have tried

1. Require JS
2. XML
3. Direct Script in html file.

But none of these methods worked.
Error in console Handlebars is not defined

Comment: I dont think handlebar is out of the box in magento. You can see all libraries which magento provide in lib/web.

Comment: @Gagan No handlebars in not the default library in magento. Or I am not sure about it.  If its default in magento how to use?